# Fabric distribution to the Play Market

Tags: google-play, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I would like to ask if there are a way to distribute your app to the Play Market Alpha/Beta testing via Fabric? I haven't found anything at Fabric's documentation and even Google, so that's interesting question I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todd from Fabric here. Right now it's not possible to distribute directly to Google play using Fabric. However, fastlane.tools is part of the tools set we also maintain and it will let you accomplish this. [Check out](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/supply) `supply` (part of fastlane) and see if it's helpful.